# Why does getaddrinfo return old IP address on a VM?

Tags: c++, networking, virtual-machine, winsock

I wrote an application that populates a combobox with the IP address for the Windows PC it's running on. It works except on one VMWare VM. I don't have access to the VM but was told it had been configured for a specific IP address and the owner changed that to get one dynamically. Here are the steps he followed:

1. Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections\Change adapter settings
2. Select appropriate NIC and open
3. Select Properties
4. Select and open Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPV4)
5. VM was configured with “use the following ip address:”, I changed to Obtain an IP address automatically
6. Run ipconfig –release in CMD
7. Run ipconfig –renew in CMD
8. Run ipconfig\dnsflush
9. Restart machine

IPConfig on the VM reports the automatically assigned IP address. My code returns the previously hard coded IP. I made a console test app with my code, using getaddrinfo, and an alternate method using gethostbyname. The gethostbyname code returns new new IP, matching IPConfig.

- Why does getaddrinfo return the old IP?
- Where is that old value stored?
- Correct way to safeguard against this behavior?

Here's the getaddrinfo code:

```
// the current method
void GetAI()
{
    std::cout << "*** getaddrinfo ***\n";
    struct addrinfo hints;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;                      //  IPv4 only
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;                //    TCP socket only
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;                //    TCP protocol only
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;                    //    intend to bind

    char szPath[128] = "";
    gethostname(szPath, sizeof(szPath));
    std::cout << "Host name is " << szPath << "." << std::endl;

    char* asciiPort = "";
    struct addrinfo* result;
    if (getaddrinfo(szPath, asciiPort, &hints, &result))
    {
        std::cout << "getaddrinfo call failed\n";
        return;
    }

    struct addrinfo* rp;
    int i(0);
    for (rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next)
    {
        const int BIGENOUGH = 46;
        WCHAR ipstringbuffer[BIGENOUGH];
        memset(ipstringbuffer, 0, BIGENOUGH);

        struct sockaddr_in* sockaddr_ipv4 = (struct sockaddr_in*) rp->ai_addr;        
        std::cout << "Address " << i++ << ": " << inet_ntoa(sockaddr_ipv4->sin_addr) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The gethostbyname code:

```
// the deprecated method
int GetHBN()
{
    std::cout << "*** gethostbyname ***\n";
    char ac[80];
    if (gethostname(ac, sizeof(ac)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error " << WSAGetLastError() <<
            " when getting local host name." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Host name is " << ac << "." << std::endl;

    hostent *phe = gethostbyname(ac);
    if (phe == 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Bad host lookup." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; phe->h_addr_list[i] != 0; ++i)
    {
        in_addr addr;
        memcpy(&addr, phe->h_addr_list[i], sizeof(in_addr));
        std::cout << "Address " << i << ": " << inet_ntoa(addr) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you ping the old IP address? Do you get a response?

Comment: @TriskalJM thanks, I just asked the VM owner, no response.

Comment: I suppose I'm a bit confused. Pinging the old IP address shouldn't require talking to the VM owner.

Comment: @TriskalJM This behavior has only been seen on a VM that's completely remote to me. The owner was using my app and saw this behavior.

Comment: Ah. Gotcha. Hopefully, they'll get back to you soon.

Comment: @TriskalJM sorry I wasn't clear. The VM owner did the ping, no response from that IP.

Comment: If it weren't for step 9) I'd guess that the old IP was cached somewhere. You're probably going to have to create your own VM and try to reproduce the problem yourself.

Comment: Is the VM multi-homed by any chance?

Comment: @TriskalJM I believe the answer is no. The VM came from one of his customers with a hard coded IP not even valid for the network he is on. He changed the setting to get a valid IP so he could connect to a device on his network. My app sits between another app on the VM and the external device.